# Firebase Autchentication with username and password not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application with unity for android. To log in users to my app I used the Firebase Authenticationw ith email and password. The problem is when running the app from the unity editor it works fine but when running the app from my mobile device it is giving me this error when click on the login button:

> 05-04 22:51:29.317: E/Unity(8114):   at
>   UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () [0x00000] in :0  05-04 22:51:29.317: E/Unity(8114):   at
>   UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in :0  05-04 22:51:29.317: E/Unity(8114):   at
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () [0x00000] in :0 
>   05-04 22:51:29.317: E/Unity(8114):   at
>   UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick
>   (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) [0x00000] in
>   :0  05-04 22:51:29.317: E/Unity(8114):   at
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClic

Comment: Is the log complete? It feels like you are missing some part of the log. Can you re add all the remaining part of log.